# What is the size need to be set for button in Any Any size classes?

Tags: ios, class, autolayout, size

Here am having button image of size (1242 * 180). I want to use this button for all phone and pad compatibility, So I used Any Any size class. Since Any*Any size class screen size is 600 * 600. Am having confusion about how to define the button width and height. Can you please suggest how to achieve this and please explain in detail to make better understanding? Make sure that I need to be on only Any * Any size classes and not with other size classes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a deeper dive into size classes and adaptive layout.
Your question doesn't really makes sense because of your lack of understanding.

Start [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started).

Comment: Ok before proceeding, I have small clarification the image resolution. If the button image size is 1242 * 180 as @3x for iPhone 6+ means, then for iPhone 6 and iPhone 4 does what size of resolution it will have? Please let me know

Comment: I will make use of the same image but will use it as 414 * 60

Comment: Ok, so now consider we have two images with size of 1242 x 180 as 3x and 414 x 60 as 2x. In this Any * any size class mode, for which size we set the width and height for the image view?

Comment: You're asking all the wrong questions. You need to wrap your head around letting go of specific sizes. Start learning how auto layout works and then dig deeper into size classes and adaptive layout.

Comment: Thanks please share some useful links for better understanding.